Why all the request values in this php method are null or undefined?
Actually, the problem is simple (but not easy for me). I've made a backend project in Laravel 11 to handle with my DB and communicate with the Stripe API, that I have successfully achieved, the communication with stripe works well, however, when I test it using Postman, the response that I receive is the following:
{
    "error": "The amount must be greater than or equal to the minimum charge amount allowed for your account and the currency set (https://docs.stripe.com/currencies#minimum-and-maximum-charge-amounts).  If you want to save a Payment Method for future use without an immediate payment, use a Setup Intent instead: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/setup-intents"
}

And what I send from postman using the POST petition is:
{
    "amount": 2434,
    "currency": "usd"
}

As you can see, there are only two values and when the response says "The amount must be greater than or equal to the minimum charge amount allowed for your account" refers to my "amount" key from my JSON object. I've checked the stripe docs and they say that the minimum quantity value of of the usd currency is $0.50 dollars, so I'm in the range. but also the usd comes to my API like undefined.
In the other hand if I do hardcoding of these two values, the response I receive is the following:
{
    "message": "Payment successful"
}

which means that my code actually work but just using hardcoding, which I don't want to use.
As far as I know, I'm not making any mistake in my code, because I'm doing what the docs say, that makes me think that the problem is something more strange like a configuration or an error into my framework's file system, but that's just my speculation.
This is the route I defined in mu api.php file to access the endpoint from postman:
Route::post('/create-checkout-session', [App\Http\Controllers\paymentController::class, 'payment']);

and this is my controller that where stripe works:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Exception;
use illuminate\Http\Request;

class paymentController extends Controller
{
    public function payment(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

            $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
                'amount' => intval($request->input('amount')),
                'currency' => $request->input('currency'),
                'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
            ]);
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Payment successful',
            ], 200);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ], 500);
        }
    }
}


I've tried using code a little bit different like this in the function, but the result was exactly the same:
            $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient([
                'api_key' => env('STRIPE_SECRET')
            ]);
            $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
                'amount' => intval($request->input('amount')),
                // 'amount' => 1000,
                'currency' => $request->input('currency'),
                // 'currency' => "usd",
                'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
            ]);

According to what I expect from the code, is to be able to catch the info that comes to my from the front (or postman) to send it to the stripe api avoiding using the "hardcoding" practice and continue developing my payment system, which I can't becaUse all I receive in the request is empty (null or undefined).
This is how my petition looks like in postman:
enter image description here

Check if your postman request is sent as a JSON object

It is. I've added an img at the end of my question to show you how does my postman petition looks like.

That "Postman" request is clearly invalid. How about consulting the manual? https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/object?lang=php

Consider assigning the $request properties you are going to use to their own variables before creating the Payment Intent.  Then, log the values before you create the Payment Intent to make sure they are what you expect.
Lastly, you can review the API requests in your Stripe Dashboard to see what parameters Stripe received on their end.  This can be useful to indicate what you actually passed to the API.

ok, i've created two new variables and use it instead in the stripe method call and checked the values of these variables but still getting the same error:             $amount = $request->input('amount');
$currency = $request->input('currency');
        dd($amount, $currency);


this is the response i get exactly with the dd() function when debugging: null // app\Http\Controllers\paymentController.php:28
null // app\Http\Controllers\paymentController.php:28

Is this a problem of mapping the request started in Postman to the variables in Laravel, or of sending the proper data from your Laravel application to Stripe?

the problem goes from postman, because i'm using it to simulate my front. From postman i send a json with just two keys, "amount": 2000 and "currency": "USD". This step is needed to make the petition to stripe, which i can't do because any value i send from postman is null.  That makes me believe that the request is actually made, but the values ​​never arrive, and still don't know why.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If sending the parameters to your Laravel application already fails, please share more details about that and remove the irrelevent parts

Based on the comment where both $currency and $amount variables are being logged as null, I think we can understand why these API calls are not successful.
I recommend adding more logging of the payload from your incoming request to identify why the amount and currency parameters you are passing to your handler function are not present in the $request variable.  There could be a lot of reasons on the front-end these values are not being set.
I do still recommend using the API logs in the Stripe Dashboard when you get stuck and are not sure why your requests are failing.  Looking at the request payload (scroll to the bottom of the JSON response) can help you understand what you actually sent to the API and that usually makes the API response more clear.

This doesn't actually answer the question

change your code to this and convert amount to Cent (1$ = 100Cent)
 $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
            'amount' => intval($request->get('amount'))*100,
            'currency' => $request->get('currency'),
            'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
        ]);


This doesn't address the issue. OP stated the following: "when I test it using Postman, the response that I receive is the following [...] what I send from postman using the POST petition is": { "amount": 2434, "currency": "usd" }
